# Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error: INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user: []

Tags: ownership

I am getting the error

> "Insert failed. First exception on row 0; first error:
>   INACTIVE_OWNER_OR_USER, operation performed with inactive user: []"

while I am updating record on custom object. The owner of the record was inactive so, I changed the record owner to an active user of the same sales region. STill getting the same error. However, when I activated the user, I was able to update the record. Can someone please help me on this issue?

Comment: Are you updating a list of records? If so unless you are using database.insert with AllOrNone = false all records will error if any of them have an inactive owner. Posting your code will help us to better understand you issue and help you

Comment: Yes Eric, I was updating a list of records.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are updating a list of records, if any one of them fail (could be #43) then all records will fail with that error. Just because it says Row 0 does not mean the first record caused the error.

That is why, when doing DML it is good practice to evaluate results and use AllorNone False:

```
Account[] a = [Select ID From Accounts];

Database.saveResult[] sr = database.update(a,false);

for(integer x=0; x<sr.size();x++){
   if(!sr[x].isSuccess()){
      system.debug(logginglevel.error, 'There was an error saving the record: ' + sr[x]); //You can debug what you need to here including info from the save result class or the whole save results
      //You may has choose to write code to do something else with the error as well
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If the user was deactivated inadvertently, you can simply reactivate the user:

1. Log in as a System Administrator, go to the Setup Menu and navigate
   to Administration Setup > Manage Users > **Users**.
2. Find the User that created the survey and reactivate them.
3. Tell your field officers to sync again.

If you do not want to reactive the user account (Example: the individual has left the organization), you can also transfer the ownership of the survey records using the following steps:

1. Click Setup in top right corner. 
   [image]
2. Navigate to Administration Setup > Data Management > Mass Transfer
   Records.
   [image]
3. Click Transfer Surveys.
   [image]
4. Enter the user the Survey records are going to be transferred from and then the user that the records will be transferred to. Click Find.
   [image]
5. Select the Survey you'd like transferred by checking the box next to the survey name If you'd like to transfer all surveys, check the box next to Title to select all records. Click Transfer.
   [image]
6. A success record will display and the user will no longer receive the 00004 Error when syncing. 
   [image]

Comment: Something I am missing here? I see nothing in the OP's question about any of the items in your response?

Comment: @Aryan Kapoor  As I already changed the owner of the record, it is not showing me in the list when I clicked on 'Find' button.